# Prove the sequence $x_n=n^2-2n$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am to prove that the sequence $(x_n)=n^2-2n$ diverges. So far this is what I have. 

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is convergent. That is, $(x_n)$ $\rightarrow$ $L \in \mathbb{R}$. As every convergent sequence is bounded, $(x_n)=(n^2-2n)$ is bounded. Then there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x_n) \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By the Archimedean property, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > M$. But $(x_n)=(n^2-2n)=n(n-2)>n$ when $n>3$, so $n(n-2)>n>M$, a contradiction. Therefore $(n^2-2n)$ diverges. 

To me this seems to be enough for the proof but I am still new to proving sequences are divergent. Does this make sense, or am I missing a vital piece of information?

Comment: Perhaps you should omit parentheses at some places but other than that it's correct.

Comment: Just factor $x$ and let $x$ approache infinity. You see that $x_{n}$ approaches infinity...

Comment: @NeedForHelp Yeah I was thinking the same as I was typing the proof out, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You did a good job. Just follow the suggestion of NeedForHelp